# How to make items corners clip inside spinner popup?

Tags: android, xamarin, spinner, clip

I've made a custom popupBackground with a corner radius of 16dp. The problem is, the items inside that popup may have a background color that doesn't go round following its parent popup, and I'm lost about how to do it since I don't see any "ClipToBounds" kind of property. The same happens with the ripple effect when tapping an item. An image representing what I have right now and the code used to generate it:

[image: Popup items]

Spinner definition:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:id="@+id/ItemOptionsSpinner"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
    android:popupBackground="@drawable/spinner_background"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

spinner_background.xml inside drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="16dp" />
    <solid android:color="?android:colorBackground" />
</shape>
```

SpinnerItemLineDropLayout.xml, the view used to display each item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/activityHorizontalPadding"
    android:paddingVertical="@dimen/activityVerticalPadding"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ItemText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/CheckImage"
        style="@style/DefaultTextAppearance.Medium.Big" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/CheckImage"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/HelpText"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_check_black_18dp"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The code I'm using inside the adapter to populate the items, just to showcase how I'm setting the background color of the item itself, depending on if the item is selected or not by the spinner:

```
public override View GetDropDownView(Int32 position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    var view = convertView ?? (parent?.Context == null ? null : LayoutInflater.FromContext(parent.Context)?.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SpinnerItemLineDropLayout, null));

    var mainLayout = view.FindViewById<ConstraintLayout>(Resource.Id.MainLayout);
    var itemTextView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ItemText);
    var checkImageView = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.CheckImage);

    itemTextView.Text = this._items[position].Text.GetText();

    checkImageView.SetImageResource(this.SelectedPosition == position ? Resource.Drawable.ic_check_black_18dp : 0);

    if (this.SelectedPosition == position)
        mainLayout.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor(view.Context.GetString(Resource.Color.colorControlHighlight)));

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reason is `BackgroundColor` of **SelectedItem** will affect the style of spinner **DropDownView**. If you not set selected color for item, you will not see this phenomenon.

If you need to set `BackgroundColor` for **SelectedItem**, there is a way to reduce the effect for **DropDownView**. But this is not a workaround, because it can not fully solve this phenomenon.

Sample code as follows:

```
if (this.SelectedPosition == position)
        
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
gradientDrawable.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);//shape
gradientDrawable.SetCornerRadius(16f);//set circle Radius
gradientDrawable.SetColor(Resource.Color.ripple_material_dark);//background color

mainLayout.SetBackgroundDrawable(gradientDrawable);//set backgroundcolor
```

Here we use `SetBackgroundDrawable` to set color, becasue this can set with a shape.

In addition, you could modify the `spinner_background.xml` code to reduce their difference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners android:radius="8dp" />
  <solid android:color="?android:colorBackground" />
</shape>
```

The effect:

[image]

============================Update==================================

As dbalboa's comment, there is another possible solution for this, and also can use `SetBackgroundColor` method to set color.That is putting `<padding android:top="15dip" android:bottom="15dip" />` inside the shape tag of the `spinner_background.xml`.

The full code as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners android:radius="8dp" />
  <padding android:top="5dip" android:bottom="5dip"/>
  <solid android:color="?android:colorBackground" />
</shape>
```

Then the effect as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. Your answer guided me through a possible solution, made a drawable for the top/bottom item with the proper corner radius, but still, the ripple effect for each item of the listview inside the popup has those corners. So ended putting `<padding android:top="15dip" android:bottom="15dip" />` inside the shape tag of the spinner_background.xml so it doesn't matter anymore if the corners are rounded or not. Too much work to make it possible.

Comment: @dbalboa Oh, that's great! You could update it as the answer, and remember to mark that. It will help others who have this issue again.

Comment: @dbalboa Thanks for marking my answer. I have updated your solution in my answer, then others who have the same issue will also know that.